# Round number to specified number of digits

Tags: haskell, numerical

Is there a simple function to round a `Double` or `Float` to a specified number of digits? I've searched here and on Hoogle (for `(Fractional a) => Int -> a -> a`), but haven't found anything.

Comment: A float or double output doesn't make much sense...

Comment: I'd suggest something like: `(fromInteger $ round $ f * (10^n)) / (10.0^^n)`

Comment: @KarolyHorvath: Is there a better output type? I don't know what else, say, 3.1415 could be represented as.

Comment: @aland: This works perfectly; maybe you should write it as an answer. Is there really no rounding function (besides `round`) in the standard libraries, though?

Comment: @amindfv I'm not very familiar with Haskell, but I haven't encountered similar functions in other languages' standard libraries.

Comment: For example, in PHP you can write `round(3.1415, 2)`, and in Ruby >= 1.9, you can write `3.14159.round(2)`

Comment: @amindfv (re: "is there a better output type?") There's a few fixed-point number types on Hackage, or you could just use a poor-man's fixed-point represented as an `Integer`.

Comment: `Double` and `Float` are always binary fractions.  If someone tells you that you can round them to a specified number of _decimal_ digits, they are lying.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Not sure whether any standard function exists, but you can do it this way:

```
 (fromInteger $ round $ f * (10^n)) / (10.0^^n)
```

Comment: Looks like noone's jumping in with a standard-library version, so I'm going to mark this as accepted -- works great; thanks.

Answer (score 15):

It depends on what you are going to do with the rounded number.

If you want to use it in calculations, you should use `Data.Decimal` from `Decimal` library.

If you want just to format the number nicely, you should use `Text.Printf` from the standard library (`base` package).

Answer (score -1):

```
λ: ((/100) $ fromIntegral $ round (0.006 * 100)) == 0.006
λ: False

λ: ((/100) $ fromIntegral $ round (0.06 * 100)) == 0.06
λ: True
```