# How can I change the precision of double value in Haskell?

Tags: haskell

I would like to change the precision of double value.

For example:

I need to get 3.14 from 3.141592653589793

I expect function like:

```
scale :: Int -> Double -> Double
> scale 2 3.141592653589793
3.14
> scale 3 3.141592653589793
3.141
```

Also, I would like to be able to choose the rounding strategy.

```
round :: ROUND -> Int -> Double -> Double
> round ROUNDUP 5 3.141592653589793
3.1416
```

- How can I do it?
- How can I apply the rounding strategy for it?

**P.S.:**

Expected behavior in Java should setScale of BigDecimal: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html

Comment: please share some example code with your desired outcome. I really don't know what you are asking for

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Round number to specified number of digits](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12450501/round-number-to-specified-number-of-digits)

Comment: Do you want to round at display time, or do calculations with an equally-precise number that is a small modification of another?  ie, do you want a function with the type `Double -> String` or a function with the type `Double -> Double`?

Comment: @Carl Yes, I am looking for Double -> Double function

Comment: @MichaelLitchard You are wrong

Comment: I can have my mind changed. How am I wrong? Where is your attempt?

Comment: I stuck with this problem from yesterday. I made some google and stackoverflow requests. I took a time read Prelude, searched for "scale" and "precision" on hoogle. Found something similar like https://hackage.haskell.org/package/rounded-0.1.0.1/docs/Numeric-Rounded.html, and then I decided to ask from someone with more experience to get a better solution. For sure I am wasn't clear with the question. I followed suggestions to clarify.

Comment: fair enough. removed downvote.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct Haskell analog of Java's `BigDecimal` is [`Fixed`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Data-Fixed.html), not `Double`. You may convert between different precisions via `realToFrac`.